# Comment flags visible on wrong page after merging questions

Tags: bug, moderator-tools, comment-flags, merged-questions, waffle-bar

I just merged a question with an answer which had a couple of comments flagged as 'No longer needed'. When I visit the merged question, the answer is gone, but the comment flags are still visible in the waffle bar:

[image]

FWIW, clicking 'Delete' still works (but affects the merge target, not this page).